# Report is not displayed correctly when there is too much data to display

Tags: html, asp.net, vbscript, internet-explorer-8

I have an interface that returns records upon client selections. The data is stored in MS-SQL and gets returned into a record set. If the records returned are lees than 4,600 (roughly), the display works fine using HTML TABLE. If the result is more than 4,600, the data is displayed in a linear mode.

Is there some sort of limitation in IE8 or do I need to put sometning in the code ?

Here is the display code:

```
<TABLE WIDTH="90%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>

<!-- DISPLAY HEADER   --->
     <TR>
<%      For i = 0 To UBound(aHeaderFields)  - 1  %>
<%      if i <> UBound(aHeaderFields) or ExportData <> "Y" then  %>
        <TD bgcolor="#FFFF99" align='center' color="yellow" style="border: solid 1px #000000" ><font size="-2" face="arial"><b><%=aHeaderFields(i)%></b></TD>
<%      end if  %>
<%    Next %>
        </TR>

<% For Rec = 0 to NbrRows  %>
<%   if aQueryResult(NbrCols,Rec) > "0" Then %>
     <TR>
     <% For i = 0 To NbrCols  %>
            <TD align=right><font size="-2" face="arial">    
<%=aQ ueryResult(i,Rec)%>&nbsp;</font></TD>
     <% Next %>
<%     if ExportData <> "Y" then  %>
<!--             <TD align=center bgcolor="<%=Bgclr(Lines)%>"><font size="-2" face="arial"><b>&nbsp;</b></font><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ViewDetail('<%=RecLine%>');"><font size="-2" face="arial">(Detail)</font></a></TD>  -->
<%     end if  %>
<%   end if  %>
   </TR>
<% Next  %>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't really a limitation to how much content is too much regarding the language, and there is no information on IE8 maximum table sizes. But with that amount of records and amount of data to be displayed, I'd assume it takes a while to generate. And now that it's cutting off the formatting....It might be a good time to possibly consider paging or auto-scrolling.

Relative Question Answer -> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174490/is-there-any-limit-on-number-of-html-elements-that-browser-can-display-without)

Also, there is JS scripts out there which can auto page the table for you, and retain the data in the script for paging. -> [Here](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/source.php)