# Maximum number of HTML ids for CSS reference in single page

Tags: html, css, limit

If I execute the following code in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000, 3), columns=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
s = Styler(df, uuid_len=0, cell_ids=False).applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow;', subset='key3')

html1 = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title</title></head><body>'
html2 = '</body></html>'
with open("output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(html1 + s.render() + html2)
```

It generates a table in HTML with cells (20000 rows and 3 columns) with the final column coloured. Each is coloured by a specific id tag and a style, e.g.:

`<style>.. #T__row19260_col2 {background-color: yellow;}  ..</style>`
`...`
`<td id="T__row19260_col2">0.50</td>`

The problem is that only the first 8192 cells are coloured (rendered in Chrome). This is suspiciously 13bits so I wonder whether it is a browser or HTML specific limitation?

There is no issue with the HTML generation.

Comment: did u test it in other browser's?

Comment: @sysix, yes Chrome and Opera has issues at 13 bits, Safari and Firefox displayed correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any limit on number of html elements, that browser can display without problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174490/is-there-any-limit-on-number-of-html-elements-that-browser-can-display-without)

Comment: @sysix, no because those answers are more or less anecdotal, are conflicting with one-another and don't address technical specifics.